# I need Integer Solution to this Equation

Tags: diophantine-equations, systems-of-equations

I need to know how to solve this equation where x and y are both variables
Find integer Solutions.
$$ \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y} = \frac{1}{2} $$
from what I know I need at least 2 equations to solve for 2 variables.
So I need a Hint

[image]

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/869218/how-to-turn-arbitrary-fractions-into-arbitrary-egyptian-fractions/869623#869623   http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1166999/find-all-integers-x-y-and-z-such-that-frac1x-frac1y-frac/1167475#1167475

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a really easy question how you need to do it is : 
$\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}$ =$\frac{1}{2}$
then $${\frac{1}{y} =\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{x}}$$
then manipulate it to get $${y=\frac{2x}{x-2}}$$
then put whatever values of x you want you will get the corresponding value of y.

If we want to get integer solutions of this equation then think like this :
Let $${2x=k(x-2)}$$

- Put $x =-2$ you get $k=1$.
- Put $x=4$ you get $k=1$
- Put $x=3$ we get $k=6$
- Put $x=6$ you will get a soln.

After that $x-2$ doesn't remain a factor of $2x$ .

Comment: The title says "I need **Positive Integer** Solution to this Equation"

Comment: in order to ensure that both values are positive, all we should need is $x \ge 3$.

Comment: @PaddlingGhost There are two words in "positive integer".

Answer (score 4):

$$y=\frac{2x}{x-2}=2\times \left(1+\frac{2}{x-2}\right)=2+\frac{4}{x-2}$$

Then $-2 \leq x < 2$ or $2<x\leq 6$. Since $y>0$, $2<x\leq 6$.

Therefore, There are three positive duplets $(x,y)$, namely, $(3,6),(4,4)$ and $(6,3)$.

Answer (score 2):

The OP seeks the pairs of integer values $(x,y)$ that are solutions of the equation $y = 2x/(x-2)$.

We observe that for large $x$ (positive or negative) the value for $y$ converges to $2$. So beyond a certain maximum value for $x$ there can not be any integer solutions.

For positive $x$ the limiting value for $y$ is approached from above. Now the nearest possible value for $y$ greater then $2$ is $3$. The accompanying value for $x$ is found to be $x = 6$.

For negative $x$ the limiting value for $y$ is approached from below. The nearest possible value for $y$ smaller than $2$ is $1$. The accompanying value for $x$ is $x = -2$.

Hence only integer values in the range $-2 \le x \le 6$ can result in an integer pair $(x,y)$. Let us check the list of candidates. We find that $(-2, 1)$, $(0,0)$, $(1, -2)$, $(3,6)$, $(4,4)$, $(6,3)$ are the only solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Denote $S=x+y$, $P=xy$. As the problem is symmetric in $x$  and $y$, we may as well suppose $x\ge y$.
$$\frac1x+\frac1y=\frac12\iff P=2S.$$
We'll examine the different possibilities according to the prime factorisation of $y$.

- First note $x$ and $y$ have the same *odd* prime factors, if any. Indeed, if an odd prime $p$ divides one of them, it divides $P=2S$, hence it divides $S$ so that it divides the other.
- If $y$ has an *odd* prime factor $p$, say $y=p^iy'$, then
  $$\frac12=\biggl\lvert \frac1x+\frac1y\biggr\rvert\le \frac2{p^i}$$
  by the triangle inequality and the hypothesis $x\ge y$. This implies $\,p^i\le 4$, so $\,p=3,\, i=1$. For the same reason,  $3$ is the only odd prime of $x$, not repeated.
- In addition, $y$ cannot be even, otherwise $\,\biggl\lvert \dfrac1x+\dfrac1y\biggr\rvert\le \dfrac 26<\dfrac12$. Finally $y=\pm3$, and 
  $$\frac1x=\frac12\mp\frac13= \frac16\enspace\text{or}\enspace\frac56.$$
  The only compatible solution is $\,x=6$.
- If $x$ and $y$ have no odd prime factor,we write $\,\lvert x\rvert=2^k,\, \lvert y\rvert=2^l\ (k\ge l)$. We have
  $$\frac12=\biggl\lvert \frac1x+\frac1y\biggr\rvert\le \frac2{2^l}$$
  which implies $2^l\le 4$, i. e. $\,l\le 2$.
- Now if $x$ and $y$ have the same sign, $P>0$ and the relation $P=2S$ shows this sign is positive. It is easy to check the only solution is $x=y=4$.
- Else $y<0<x$. Then $\,\dfrac12=\dfrac1x+\dfrac1y<\dfrac1x$, so $\,x<2$, thus $x=1$, and $y=-2$.

**Summary:**
Taking into account we've supposed $x\ge y$, there are $5$ solutions:
$$\bigl\{(1,-2), (-2,1), (4,4), (6,3), (3,6)\bigr\}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Because you have more vairables then equations, i.e. an [undetermined system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underdetermined_system) , so you can have either infinitely many solutions or no solutions.

Provided $xy \neq 0$, one obtains 
$$2x+2y = xy.$$ 
Then express $x$ in terms of $y$, i.e. 
$$x = \frac{2y}{y-2}$$

Take a value for $y$ without violating $xy \neq 0$, substitute into the above euqation. If the value of $x$ also does not violate the assumption, then you have obtained one solution.

Since you are looking for positive integer solutions, observe that $y>2$ is required. Besides, $\frac{2y}{y-2}\in \mathbb{N}^+$, which can be found by exhaustion.

So any pair $(\frac{2y}{y-2},y)$ with integer valued $y>2$ is a solution.

Comment: So when are $y, \frac{2y}{y-2}$ both integers?