# Solve for positive integers: $\frac{4}{13}=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}$

Tags: number-theory

Solve for $x,y,z\in\mathbb{N}$

$\frac{4}{13}=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}$

I tried by some general methods but they didn't help me.

Comment: The formula there.   http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/450280/erdös-straus-conjecture/831870#831870

Comment: "I tried by some general methods but they didn't help me." Oh yeah? Which ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wlog. $x\le y\le z$. Then there are only finitely many cases for $x$ to consider as  $\frac3x\ge \frac4{13}>\frac1x$ implies $\frac{13}4<x\le\frac{39}{4}$, i.e. $4\le x\le 9$. For each of these $x$, there are again only finitely many $y$ to consider, as we have $\frac2y\ge\frac4{13}-\frac1x>\frac1y$, i.e. $\frac1{\frac4{13}-\frac1x}<y\le \frac2{\frac4{13}-\frac1x}$. For each such $y$ check if $z=\frac1{\frac4{13}-\frac1x-\frac1y}$ is an interger (and $x\le y\le z$). So all in all this is a finite task.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: [Erdős-Strauss-Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Straus_conjecture) and [Egyptian-Fraction-Expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_fraction)

You can get

$$\frac 4 {13} = \frac 1 4+ \frac 1 {18}+ \frac 1 {468}$$

Try using the expansion algorithm:

$$\frac{x}{y}=\frac{1}{\lceil y/x\rceil}+\underbrace{\frac{(-y)\,\bmod\, x}{y\lceil y/x\rceil}}_{*}$$

On the LHS you have your input. Then you can calculate the two terms on the RHS. The first one is the first fraction of the expansion while you have to expand the second one $(*)$ again with the same algorithm.

Comment: But I want solution to this case. Can you state some method to find it?

Comment: I did post the solution and you can use the given expansion algorithm.

Comment: Is there a condition on $m,n$ for which $\frac{m}{n}=x^-1+y^-1$ is solvable where $x,y\in\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Hint: Write $m/n$ as $(x+y)/(xy)$ but this is a totally different problem.

Comment: Yes then I made quadratic equation, made discriminant perfect square but then what to do?

Comment: Egyptian Fractions. I learnt something new today. It's interesting how the greedy algorithm leads to inelegant results.

Comment: @SatvikMashkaria I suggest you open a new question for this, because it is a pretty different problem.

Comment: Yes got it. Thanks

Comment: @flawr but this algorithm doesn't give desired result for $\frac{4}{73}$.

Comment: @SatvikMashkaria Can you provide the result you've gotten when using the algorithm?

Comment: @flawr $\frac{4}{73}=\frac{1}{19}+\frac{3}{1387}$ and $\frac{3}{1387}=\frac{1}{463}+\frac{2}{642181}$

Comment: Ah ok, well the result is correct but of course this is only a general (greedy) algorithm for calculating an egyptian fraction expansion. If this one does not work you can use another representation, I suggest reading the wikipedia articles about this topic.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to try brute force.  The smallest $x$ for which $\frac1x < \frac{4}{13}$ is $x=4$, so I will try that, and then I need $$\frac1y + \frac1z = \frac4{13}-\frac14 = \frac3{52}.$$

Now it is clear that $\frac3{52} = \frac1{52} + \frac2{52} = \frac1{52} +\frac1{26}$ so I am done.  But if I didn't have that happy inspiration, I could repeat the process and try $y=18$ because that is the smallest $y$ for which $\frac1y \le \frac3{52}$.  Then I find $$\frac1z = \frac3{52} - \frac1{18} = \frac1{468}$$ and I have a second solution.

I cannot claim this is a general method, but it did work with minimal effort and no theory.

Comment: The greedy algorithm is guaranteed to work, but it can be very inefficient in the sense that there may be shorter expansions. But it’s surely the obvious thing to try here if one doesn’t have any cleverer ideas.

Comment: It is guaranteed to find *an* expansion, but it may not find the shortest one.  This problem required an expansion of three terms.  The greedy algorithm found one, in this case, but is not guaranteed to do so.

Comment: I know: that’s pretty much what I said in my comment.

Comment: You said it was guaranteed to work, but for this problem, that is not the case.

Comment: It is guaranteed to work in the sense in which I meant it: it always produces an Egyptian fraction expansion. The ‘but it’ clause clearly implies that it might not have produced a $3$-term expansion here, and the final sentence clearly implies that it might not have worked.