# Prove that the Diophantine equation has only one solution for $a,b,c$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that the Diophantine equation

$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}=1$

has only one solution for positive integers $a,b,c$   with $a<b<c$

Comment: @DietrichBurde yes but the question is to prove that there exist only one

Comment: I saw this on MSE already, but can't find the duplicate now. But see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1015428/solve-for-positive-integers-frac413-frac1x-frac1y-frac1z) for ideas.

Comment: The formula in General there.    http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/450280/erdös-straus-conjecture/831830#831830

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there must be a number smaller than $3$ since there is going to be a number larger than $3$. So $a=2$. we now want $\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}=\frac{1}{2}$ with $b$ and $c$ larger than $2$. If we take $\frac{1}{4}$ we need to repeat it, so we need a number larger than $\frac{1}{4}$, this forces us to take $\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: Probably easier to say if the average of three distinct numbers is $\frac 1{3}$, then one of them is bigger than $\frac{1}3$, rather than the more peculiar "there must be a number smaller, so there must be a number larger" argument. Same for the $\frac 12$ case - the average of two distinct numbers is $\frac 14$, so one of them must be larger than $\frac 14$.

Comment: yeah, that's clearer.

Comment: $\frac13 < \frac14$

Comment: @Goos it's fixed

Answer (score 3):

Hint:
$$1\geq\frac{1}{a}>\frac{1}{b}>\frac{1}{c}$$ so , $$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}<\frac{3}{a}$$.
If $a>3$ the sum is less than $1$.
Check the cases $a=2$ , $a=1$.

Comment: If $a\geq 3$, the sum is less then $1$, actually.