# Find the number of sets of $(a,b,c)$ for $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}=\frac{29}{72}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, quadratics

> If $\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{1}{b}+\dfrac{1}{c}=\dfrac{29}{72},\ \ c<b<a<60,\ \ \{a,b,c\}\in\mathbb{N} $.
>
> How many sets of $(a,b,c)$ exists ?

**Options**

$a.)\ 3 \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad b.)\ 4 \\
c.)\ 5 \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \color{green}{d.)\ 6} \\ $

by trial and error i found

$$\begin{array}{c|c} 
2 & 72 \\ \hline
2 &36  \\ \hline
2 &18 \\ \hline
3 &9 \\ \hline
3 &3 \\ \hline
 &1\\
 \end{array}$$

$\\~\\~\\$

$$\dfrac{29}{72}=\dfrac{18}{72}+\dfrac{9}{72}+\dfrac{2}{72}= \dfrac{1}{c}+\dfrac{1}{b}+\dfrac{1}{a}\\~\\
\implies (a,b,c)=(36,8,4)$$

This question is from chapter quadratic equations.

I look for a short and simple way.

I have studied maths up to $12$th grade.

Comment: I think easier approach(yet trial and error) , is to write down all the possible dividers  and try to reach  29 :$24,18,12,9,8,6,4,3,2,1$. so for example you found $(18,9,2)$ you can see that $(18,8,3)$ is also good. thus $\frac14 + \frac19 + \frac1{24}$

Comment: The avg time to solve such questions with options given is $1-3$ min , so that approach seems a little time consuming for me.

Comment: so I guess I have to return to elementary school again :). anyway it is not that long .. if you really try to use it.(because you know the bigger must be at least 12. because 9+8+6 < 29

Comment: Also I am not interested in necessarily finding all actual solutions , but  the number of solutions.so I think it might have some combinatorics/lcm involved.

Comment: but what I wrote above is basically "combinatorics": how many ways you can reach 29 by adding 3 numbers. it should take less than 60 seconds if you really try it.

Comment: @d_e: why don't you post an answer for that , so that it will be better to review it for me.

Comment: well, my answer apprently not complete. I guessed $a,b,c$ must be dividers of 72, but it not neccesarry the case. if indeed the answer is $6$ than indeed I'm missing a solution. so sorry, I don't have a 'good' way of solving this. only to do trial and error more systematically as the answer below pointed out.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/450280/erdös-straus-conjecture/831870#831870

Answer (score 3):

In this type of problem,
you have to go through cases,
usually on the extreme variables.

Initially,
$\dfrac{1}{c} < \dfrac{29}{72}$,
so
$c > \dfrac{72}{29}
=2+\dfrac{14}{29}
$,
so $c \ge 3$.

In the other direction,
since
$\dfrac{1}{c}+\dfrac{1}{b}+\dfrac{1}{a}
< \dfrac{3}{c}
$,
$\dfrac{3}{c} > \dfrac{29}{72}$
or
$c < \dfrac{216}{29}
$
or $c \le 7$.

Looking at $a$,
$\dfrac{3}{a} < \dfrac{29}{72}$,
or $a \ge 8$.

For each $3 \le c \le 7$,
compute
$d
=\dfrac{72}{29}-\dfrac{1}{c}
$.
Then
$\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{1}{b} = d$,
so
$\dfrac{2}{a} < d < \dfrac{2}{b}$
or
$c+1 \le b < \dfrac{2}{d}$.

For each $c+1 \le b < \dfrac{2}{d}$,
compute
$\dfrac{1}{d}-\dfrac{1}{b}$
and see if that
is of the form
$\dfrac{1}{a}$
for $a > b$.

I'll leave the actual computation
to you.

Answer (score 2):

This cannot be done without a somewhat clumsy search. The aim then is to keep the number of cases to check as small as possible.

We are looking for integer solutions of
$${1\over a}+{1\over b}+{1\over c}={29\over72}$$
with $1\leq c<b<a$.

The conditions
$${1\over c}<{29\over 72},\qquad{1\over c}+{1\over c+1}+{1\over c+2}\geq{29\over 72}$$
imply $3\leq c\leq 6$.

Given $c$ in this range, put $$q:={29\over 72}-{1\over c}\ .$$ We then have to solve
$${1\over a}+{1\over b}=q\ .$$
The conditions for $b$ are
$$b>c,\qquad {1\over b}<q, \qquad {1\over b}>{q\over2}\ ,$$
the third of these in order to guarantee $a>b$. This enforces
$$\max\left\{{1\over q},c\right\}<b<{2\over q}\ .$$
Given $b$ in this range we have to check whether the resulting
$$ a={b\over bq-1}$$
is integer. If yes, we accept the triple $(a,b,c)$. Mathematica found $7$ such triples, three of which violated the extra condition $a<60$. Here is the output:

[image]

Comment: So only 4 satisfy all requirements, which I got also by another long-ish (not clever) method. +1, still wonder if there is some clever way without trying so many cases...

Comment: @coffeemath You can get pretty far (whittling down to six cases) based on $72=2^33^2$.

Answer (score 0):

If $c<b<a<60$ the answer is $4$.

Here is the method for finding the complete solutions $(a,b,c)$ of equation $\frac{29}{72}=\frac{1}{c}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{a} ~(1)$.

Let $0<c<b<a<60, a,b,c∈N^{+} ⟹ \frac{29}{72}>\frac{1}{c} ⟹c>\frac{72}{29}⟹c≥3$.

On the other hand $\frac{1}{72}=\frac{1}{29c}+\frac{1}{29b}+\frac{1}{29a}⟹29c≤3×72$ (recalling $~ c<b<a<60$)$⟹c≤\frac{216}{29}$, so that $c∈[3,4,5,6,7]$.

Hence find the equation $(1)$ solutions now equivalent to find solutions for below five reduced equations:

$\frac{29}{72}-\frac{1}{3}=\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{a}⟹\frac{5}{72}=\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{a};~$

$\frac{29}{72}-\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{a}⟹\frac{11}{72}=\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{a};~$

$\frac{29}{72}-\frac{1}{5}=\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{a}⟹\frac{73}{360}=\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{a};~$

$\frac{29}{72}-\frac{1}{6}=\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{a}⟹\frac{17}{72}=\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{a};~$

$\frac{29}{72}-\frac{1}{7}=\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{a}⟹\frac{131}{504}=\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{a};~$

Find above five equations two unit fractions expansion, we have following solutions, becasue $c<b<a<60$, so the the answer is 4, the solutions are $(a,b,c)=(36,24,3),(36,8,4),(24,9,4),(9,8,6)$.

[image]

Comment: This answer does not add anything useful, not to mention the lack of  explanation for how the solutions are obtained.

Comment: @VTand, see above general algorithm, in fact it is a standard algorithm for finding any fraction $\frac{m}{n}$ fixed terms (if have) unit fractions expansion problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the inevitable case-checking down to 6 cases by thinking about prime powers dividing fraction denominators. First, as with other answers, we can conclude that $c\leq7$: $$\frac{29}{72}=\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}<\frac{3}{c}\implies c<\frac{216}{29}\implies c\leq7$$

Meanwhile, you can't have a denominator of $72$ in the sum of three fractions without one of the three original denominators divisible by $9$. It must be $a$ or $b$ since $c\leq7$. Likewise, $a$ or $b$ must be divisible by $8$. And since all denominators are less than $60$, neither $a$ nor $b$ is divisible by *both* $8$ and $9$. So between $a$ and $b$, one is divisible by $9$ and the other by $8$.

So I disregard the ordering $b<a$ and imagine those two denominators to be $x=9m$ and $y=8n$.

$$\frac{1}{9m}+\frac{1}{8n}+\frac{1}{c}=\frac{29}{72}$$
$$\frac{8}{m}+\frac{9}{n}+\frac{72}{c}=29\tag{*}$$

with $m\leq6, n\leq7, c\leq 7$.

Now we cannot have $n=7$, or else $c$ must also be $7$ (because $7$ would need to divide at least two of the denominators in (*)). But then $\frac{81}{7}$ does not reduce, and $7$ would have to also divide $m$, which is a contradiction. So $m\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and $n\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.

We cannot have $n$ being even either, or else $\frac{9}{n}$ does not reduce to an integer and at lease one of $m,z$ would have to be divisible by $16$. So $m\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and $n\in\{1,3,5\}$.

Similarly we cannot have $m$ divisible by $3$, or else $\frac{8}{m}$ does not reduce to an integer and at lease one of $n,z$ would have to be divisible by $27$. So $m\in\{1,2,4,5\}$ and $n\in\{1,3,5\}$.

And we cannot have either $m,n$ equal to $5$. If $n=5$, at least one of $m,c$ would have to equal $5$. But neither $\frac{8}{5}+\frac{9}{5}$ nor $\frac{9}{5}+\frac{72}{5}$ is an integer, so actually all three denominators would have to be $5$, and $\frac{89}{5}\neq29$.

And if $m=5$, at least one of $n,c$ would have to equal $5$. Even if $n=5$, then since  $\frac{8}{5}+\frac{9}{5}$ is not an integer, $c$ would have to also be $5$. So either way, $c=5$. But just assuming $m,c=5$ means $\frac{9}{n}=13$, which is not possible.

So $m\in\{1,2,4\}$ and $n\in\{1,3\}$. Now there are only $6$ cases to examine (*) and see if $z$ is an integer. Four of the cases pass and two do not. The four that pass are

$$\frac{8}{1}+\frac{9}{1}+\frac{72}{6}=29\quad \frac{8}{1}+\frac{9}{3}+\frac{72}{4}=29\quad \frac{8}{4}+\frac{9}{1}+\frac{72}{4}=29\quad \frac{8}{4}+\frac{9}{3}+\frac{72}{3}=29$$

Recalling $x=9m$ and $y=8n$, the original triples $(x,y,z)$ are $(9,8,6)$, $(9,24,4)$, $(36,8,4)$, and $(36,24,3)$.