# An interesting equation in natural numbers

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Let $n$ be a fixed natural number. How to solve the following equation in natural numbers:
$$ \frac{1}{x_1} + \frac{2}{x_2} + \cdots + \frac{n}{x_n} = 1 $$ 
(I can find many soltions but I am looking for all solutions)

Comment: What are $x_1...$ integers or natural numbers

Comment: @ArchisWelankar natural numbers

Comment: It is sufficient to solve the equation.  $$\frac{1}{x_1}+\frac{2}{x_2}+\frac{3}{x_3}=\frac{a}{b}$$  Number  $a,b - $ will be set.  Which are obtained if we ask the other numbers at their discretion.

Comment: You can use this formula.   http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/450280/erdös-straus-conjecture/831870#831870

Comment: I see what you mean that it's trivial to write down some solutions e.g. $x_i=in$.  But do you have a good reason to believe it's easy to characterize all solutions?  That seems like it may be intractable.

Comment: @GregoryGrant I have no reason to believe  that this is an easy queastion, it may be even an open question.

Comment: Well it's easy if $n=2$.  The condition $x_2-2\mid x_2$ means $x_2$ can't be very big, it would have to be no bigger than $4$.

Comment: @GregoryGrant It would be easier for n=1.

Comment: Well I was working on $n=3$ and making some headway, but the sarcasm I can do without, so I think I'll look elsewhere for my late night entertainment.

Answer (score 0):

We assume x1 < x2/2 < x3/3 ... and We may write 1/(x1/1) +1/(x2/2) +1/(x3/3) +. . . 1/(xn/n)=1
Number of terms is n then 1/(x1/1)<1/n. taking x1 an arbitrary value satisfying 1/(x1) < 1/n and finding equation:

1/(x2/2) +1/(x3/3) +. . . 1(xn/n)=1-1/x1

Now 1/(x2/2) < 1-1/x1 defines lowest value and also n-1/(x2/2) > 1-1/x1 defines
upper value of x2. we take a value in this range. In this way we can find xi; i=3, 4, 5 ... .

Example: 1/2 + 2/6 + 3/21 + 4/172 + 5/9030 = 1