# Find all positive integers $k,m,n$ satisfying: $\frac1k+\frac1m+\frac1n=\frac{1}{1996}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

> Find all positive integers $k,m,n$ satisfying: $\frac1k+\frac1m+\frac1n=\frac{1}{1996}$

The trivial answer is: $k=m=n=3*1996$
$kmn=1996(km+mn+nk)=499\times4\times(km+mn+nk)$ , now $kmn$ must be divisible by all factors in RHS , but how can we get more info about $k,m,n$ ?

Comment: $\frac{1}{1996}=\frac{1}{1997}+\frac{1}{3986012}=\frac{1}{1998}+\frac{1}{1994004}=\frac{1}{1999}+\frac{1}{1330002}+\frac{1}{2653356650004}$...There are many possible solutions.

Comment: @McCheng How did you find such large numbers? What's the properties of such numbers?

Comment: For example, $\frac{1}{x}=\frac{1}{x+1}+\frac{1}{x(x+1)}$

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/450280/erd%C3%B6s-straus-conjecture/831870#831870

Comment: @McCheng Is it possible to find solutions like $k=2499,m=9996,n=1247001$ using your method??

Comment: It is easy to write $\frac{1}{x}=\frac{1}{x+503}+\frac{503}{x(x+503)}$. In this case $x=1996$, so $x(x+503)=4988004$. After trial and errors, we may see that $4988004=499*9996$, arriving to your answer.

Comment: You can also use $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{6}=1$ and $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{4}=1$ to get other answers.

Answer (score 4):

**Solutions only for $k=m$.**

Assume $k=m$, then $\frac{1}{1996}=\frac{2n+m}{mn}$ or $mn=1996\cdot 2n + 1996m$ or $$mn - 1996\cdot 2n - 1996\cdot m =0$$

or $$(n-1996)(m-1996\cdot 2)=2\cdot 1996^2$$

or:

$$(n-1996)(m-1996\cdot 2)=2\cdot 1996^2.$$

If $d\mid 2\cdot 1996^2$ then $n=1996+d$ and $m-1996\cdot 2 = \frac{2\cdot 1996^2}{d}$ or $m=1996\cdot 2 + \frac{2\cdot 1996^2}{d}$.

Since $1996=2^2\cdot 499$, then $d\mid 2^5\cdot 499^2$, which yields already 18 possible solutions.

The extreme case, when $d=1$, gives $n=1997$ and $m=k=2\cdot 1996 \cdot 1997$. When $d=2\cdot 1996^2$, $n=1996(1+2\cdot 1996)$ and $m=k=1996\cdot 2 + 1$.

**Algorithm for finding all soluions**

If you assume $k<m,n$, then $1996<k<3\cdot 1996$, and you want:

$$\frac{k-1996}{1996k}=\frac{1}m+\frac1n$$

Or $$(k-1996)^2mn - 1996k(k-1996)(m+n)$$

or $$\left((k-1996)m-1996k\right)\left((k-1996)n-1996k\right)=1996^2k^2$$

So you need to find a divisor $d\mid 1996^2k^2$ where both $k-1996\mid d+1996k$ and $k-1996\mid \frac{1996^2k^2}{d}+1996k$, or if:

$$k-1996\mid d+1996^2\\k-1996\mid \frac{1996^2k^2}{d}+1996^2$$

We could write a computer program to enumerate such pairs $(k,d)$ pretty easily, and then solve for $m,n$.

My ruby script turned up 1517 answers, assuming $k\leq m\leq n$, which turns out to be too large for Stack Exchange to handle as raw data, but here is the complete list of $(k,m)$ pairs.

```
1997 3986013
1997 3986014
1997 3986016
1997 3986020
1997 3986028
1997 3986511
1997 3987010
1997 3988008
1997 3990004
1997 3993996
1997 4235013
1997 4484014
1997 4982016
1997 5978020
1997 7970028
1997 3988009
1997 3990006
1997 3994000
1997 4001988
1997 4017964
1997 4982515
1997 5979018
1997 7972024
1998 1994005
1998 1994006
1998 1994008
1998 1994012
1998 1994020
1998 1994503
1998 1995002
1998 1996000
1998 1997996
1998 2001988
1998 2243005
1998 2492006
1998 2990008
1998 3986012
1998 1994007
1998 1994010
1998 1994016
1998 1994028
1998 1994052
1998 1995501
1998 1996998
1998 1999992
1998 2005980
1998 2017956
1998 2741007
1998 3488010
1998 1994013
1998 1994022
1998 1994040
1998 1994076
1998 1994148
1998 1998495
1998 2002986
1998 2011968
1998 2029932
1998 2065860
1998 1994031
1998 1994058
1998 1994112
1998 1994220
1998 1994436
1998 2007477
1998 2020950
1998 2047896
1998 2101788
1998 2209572
1998 1994085
1998 1994166
1998 1994328
1998 1994652
1998 1995300
1998 2034423
1998 2074842
1998 2155680
1998 2317356
1998 2640708
1998 1994247
1998 1994490
1998 1994976
1998 1995948
1998 1997892
1998 2115261
1998 2236518
1998 2479032
1998 2964060
1998 3934116
1998 1994733
1998 1995462
1998 1996920
1998 1999836
1998 2005668
1998 2357775
1998 2721546
1998 3449088
1998 1994041
1998 1994078
1998 1994152
1998 1994300
1998 1994596
1998 2012467
1998 2030930
1998 2067856
1998 2141708
1998 2289412
1998 1994115
1998 1994226
1998 1994448
1998 1994892
1998 1995780
1998 2049393
1998 2104782
1998 2215560
1998 2437116
1998 2880228
1998 1994337
1998 1994670
1998 1995336
1998 1996668
1998 1999332
1998 2160171
1998 2326338
1998 2658672
1998 3323340
1998 1995003
1998 1996002
1998 1998000
1998 2001996
1998 2009988
1998 2492505
1998 2991006
1998 3988008
1998 1997001
1998 1999998
1998 2005992
1998 2017980
1998 2041956
1998 3489507
1998 2002995
1998 2011986
1998 2029968
1998 2065932
1998 2137860
1998 2020977
1998 2047950
1998 2101896
1998 2209788
1998 2425572
1998 1995373
1998 1996742
1998 1999480
1998 2004956
1998 2015908
1998 2677135
1998 3360266
1998 1998111
1998 2002218
1998 2010432
1998 2026860
1998 2059716
1998 2006325
1998 2018646
1998 2043288
1998 2092572
1998 2191140
1998 2030967
1998 2067930
1998 2141856
1998 2289708
1998 2585412
1998 2104893
1998 2215782
1998 2437560
1998 2881116
1998 3768228
1998 2326671
1998 2659338
1998 3324672
1998 2992005
1999 1330002
1999 1330004
1999 1330334
1999 1331332
1999 1496002
1999 1994004
1999 1331334
1999 1335332
1999 1995002
2000 998001
2000 998002
2000 998004
2000 998008
2000 998016
2000 998032
2000 998064
2000 998128
2000 998256
2000 998499
2000 998998
2000 999996
2000 1001992
2000 1005984
2000 1013968
2000 1029936
2000 1061872
2000 1125744
2000 1247001
2000 1496002
2000 1994004
2000 998005
2000 998010
2000 998020
2000 998040
2000 998080
2000 998160
2000 998320
2000 998640
2000 999280
2000 1000495
2000 1002990
2000 1007980
2000 1017960
2000 1037920
2000 1077840
2000 1157680
2000 1317360
2000 1636720
2000 998025
2000 998050
2000 998100
2000 998200
2000 998400
2000 998800
2000 999600
2000 1001200
2000 1004400
2000 1010475
2000 1022950
2000 1047900
2000 1097800
2000 1197600
2000 1397200
2000 1796400
2000 998125
2000 998250
2000 998500
2000 999000
2000 1000000
2000 1002000
2000 1006000
2000 1014000
2000 1030000
2000 1060375
2000 1122750
2000 1247500
2000 1497000
2000 1996000
2000 998625
2000 999250
2000 1000500
2000 1003000
2000 1008000
2000 1018000
2000 1038000
2000 1078000
2000 1158000
2000 1309875
2000 1621750
2000 1001125
2000 1004250
2000 1010500
2000 1023000
2000 1048000
2000 1098000
2000 1198000
2000 1398000
2000 1798000
2000 1013625
2000 1029250
2000 1060500
2000 1123000
2000 1248000
2000 1498000
2001 798800
2001 798899
2001 800396
2001 998000
2001 798804
2001 799398
2001 798801
2001 798828
2001 802392
2001 1247001
2001 798836
2001 803390
2001 798813
2001 799020
2001 826344
2001 798882
2001 964068
2001 798905
2001 800492
2001 1009976
2001 799434
2001 802608
2001 1273947
2001 798805
2001 798892
2001 810376
2001 798834
2001 868260
2001 799008
2001 824847
2001 1215564
2001 799066
2001 1331332
2001 800400
2001 998499
2001 808404
2001 811072
2001 872436
2001 826413
2001 1240620
2001 799472
2001 882731
2001 802836
2001 1302390
2001 800313
2001 823020
2001 829748
2001 810405
2001 984492
2001 868434
2001 887777
2001 1332666
2002 665999
2002 666000
2002 666004
2002 666165
2002 666664
2002 668660
2002 748999
2002 998000
2002 666001
2002 666008
2002 666036
2002 667163
2002 670656
2002 684628
2002 1247001
2002 666015
2002 666064
2002 666260
2002 674149
2002 698600
2002 796404
2002 666006
2002 666028
2002 669658
2002 680636
2002 666050
2002 666204
2002 691614
2002 768460
2002 666358
2002 667436
2002 845306
2002 666039
2002 666160
2002 666644
2002 686125
2002 746504
2002 988020
2002 666281
2002 667128
2002 670516
2002 806883
2002 1229536
2002 667975
2002 673904
2002 697620
2002 666003
2002 666016
2002 666068
2002 668161
2002 674648
2002 700596
2002 666029
2002 666120
2002 666484
2002 681135
2002 726544
2002 908180
2002 666211
2002 666848
2002 669396
2002 771953
2002 1089816
2002 666094
2002 666380
2002 713570
2002 856284
2002 666666
2002 668668
2002 998998
2002 670670
2002 684684
2002 666523
2002 668096
2002 674388
2002 927641
2002 669669
2002 680680
2002 724724
2002 691691
2002 768768
2002 1077076
2002 666055
2002 666224
2002 666900
2002 694109
2002 778440
2002 1115764
2002 666393
2002 667576
2002 672308
2002 862771
2002 668759
2002 677040
2002 710164
2002 667238
2002 670956
2002 1284426
2002 674674
2002 700700
2002 726726
2002 908908
2002 672815
2002 693264
2002 775060
2002 713713
2002 856856
2002 999999
2004 499999
2004 500000
2004 500002
2004 500497
2004 500996
2004 501994
2004 748999
2004 998000
2004 500001
2004 500004
2004 500010
2004 501495
2004 502992
2004 505986
2004 500007
2004 500016
2004 500034
2004 504489
2004 508980
2004 517962
2004 500165
2004 500332
2004 500666
2004 583331
2004 666664
2004 833330
2004 500499
2004 501000
2004 502002
2004 749997
2004 999996
2004 501501
2004 503004
2004 506010
2004 527887
2004 555776
2004 611554
2004 583665
2004 667332
2004 834666
2004 750999
2005 445108
2005 499998
2005 444665
2005 449100
2005 444670
2005 444709
2005 800396
2005 445110
2005 449120
2005 480398
2005 802000
2006 400398
2006 401196
2006 499998
2006 400401
2006 400452
2006 407184
2006 400860
2006 458082
2006 400492
2006 412174
2006 401200
2006 500497
2006 407218
2006 401790
2006 412233
2006 589764
2007 364180
2007 364270
2007 365268
2007 499998
2007 364194
2007 445108
2007 365274
2007 377316
2007 445554
2008 333998
2008 334000
2008 334008
2008 334330
2008 335328
2008 339320
2008 499998
2008 334081
2008 334332
2008 335336
2008 339352
2008 375747
2008 500996
2008 375998
2008 502000
2009 308460
2009 308484
2009 308812
2009 308976
2009 315700
2009 409836
2010 286569
2010 286572
2010 287424
2010 499998
2010 286570
2010 286580
2010 286925
2010 289420
2010 286575
2010 286620
2010 299400
2010 286590
2010 286740
2010 291915
2010 329340
2010 286626
2010 287028
2010 300897
2010 401196
2010 286760
2010 334330
2010 287430
2010 293460
2010 501495
2010 289440
2010 294264
2010 289775
2010 312220
2010 402000
2010 334665
2012 250998
2012 251496
2012 499998
2012 251500
2012 501994
2013 236350
2013 250997
2013 236526
2013 236352
2013 241516
2013 236357
2013 247005
2013 236478
2013 243512
2013 236436
2013 365268
2013 241560
2013 239852
2013 243573
2013 448228
2014 223332
2014 223552
2014 250997
2014 223364
2014 227544
2014 223972
2014 303392
2014 223342
2014 223554
2014 227582
2014 228324
2014 318212
2015 211692
2015 220558
2015 211770
2015 389220
2015 213460
2015 232035
2015 212784
2015 233740
2015 214210
2016 201197
2016 201200
2016 201248
2016 201596
2016 207584
2016 303392
2016 250997
2016 201198
2016 201216
2016 201504
2016 203592
2016 239520
2016 201204
2016 201312
2016 203040
2016 202095
2016 215568
2016 201240
2016 201888
2016 206586
2016 287424
2016 201213
2016 201456
2016 205344
2016 233532
2016 201208
2016 201376
2016 202594
2016 223552
2016 201201
2016 201264
2016 202272
2016 209580
2016 335328
2016 201222
2016 201600
2016 207648
2016 251496
2016 201348
2016 203616
2016 239904
2016 220059
2016 202104
2016 215712
2016 314370
2016 201236
2016 201824
2016 211232
2016 206087
2016 279440
2016 201432
2016 204960
2016 230538
2016 201285
2016 202608
2016 223776
2016 377244
2016 201726
2016 209664
2016 336672
2016 204372
2016 252000
2018 183088
2018 183133
2020 167997
2020 167998
2020 168163
2020 168662
2020 250997
2020 168000
2020 169660
2020 168005
2020 168030
2020 172155
2020 184630
2020 168064
2020 201596
2020 168165
2020 168670
2020 251995
2020 169680
2020 171397
2020 181598
2020 202000
2020 253005
2021 161676
2021 162540
2021 161680
2021 161445
2022 155228
2022 155688
2022 168163
2022 155694
2022 225116
2023 149700
2023 149583
2023 149702
2023 153748
2023 150280
2023 169932
2025 139376
2025 161676
2025 139401
2025 139720
2025 139380
2025 202095
2025 140130
2025 149700
2025 139500
2025 162000
2025 139725
2025 149850
2028 126497
2028 126746
2028 250997
2028 126498
2028 127245
2028 126501
2028 128742
2028 126503
2028 129740
2028 126516
2028 136227
2028 126555
2028 155688
2028 126581
2028 168662
2028 126750
2028 252993
2028 127257
2028 127595
2028 129792
2028 136383
2028 140777
2028 169338
2029 122724
2029 122754
2030 119173
2030 119760
2030 119175
2030 139720
2030 119196
2030 119245
2030 119190
2030 119364
2030 119770
2030 202594
2030 125860
2030 124120
2030 121597
2032 112664
2032 112774
2032 119760
2032 112776
2032 126746
2032 127000
2033 109780
2033 113772
2033 109675
2033 109782
2033 113848
2034 106839
2034 107784
2034 112774
2034 107124
2034 107802
2034 112887
2035 104790
2035 104291
2035 109780
2035 104155
2035 104340
2035 104192
2035 109890
2036 101796
2036 101800
2037 99168
2040 92542
2040 92544
2040 92814
2040 92568
2040 95808
2040 99800
2040 92550
2040 92560
2040 94810
2040 92760
2040 119760
2040 92548
2040 93313
2040 92616
2040 101796
2040 93432
2040 92565
2040 92820
2040 127245
2040 93160
2040 169660
2040 99960
2040 92752
2040 118762
2040 95064
2040 93330
2040 102000
2040 113560
2041 90532
2041 90818
2043 86826
2043 89892
2045 83436
2046 81836
2046 82335
2046 81708
2046 81686
2046 92814
2046 81840
2046 139221
2046 84444
2046 82522
2047 80114
2047 80339
2048 78612
2048 79872
2048 79840
2049 77844
2049 77179
2050 75848
2050 75775
2050 87325
2050 81836
2050 75850
2050 82000
2052 73140
2052 73353
2052 73143
2052 80838
2052 73278
2052 107784
2052 73150
2052 75848
2052 73188
2052 85329
2052 73359
2052 81054
2052 73758
2052 75924
2052 85671
2054 70686
2054 78052
2055 69522
2055 69860
2055 69870
2057 67308
2057 71148
2057 67864
2057 67320
2057 93313
2057 67881
2058 66367
2058 66255
2058 73353
2058 69972
2060 64371
2060 64870
2060 67365
2060 64272
2060 64375
2060 64890
2062 62360
2062 62375
2064 60592
2064 71856
2064 60585
2064 60720
2064 60587
2064 61232
2064 64371
2064 60630
2064 60802
2064 64500
2065 59880
2065 69860
2065 59885
2067 58110
2067 58383
2068 57330
2068 57385
2068 57332
2068 57343
2068 57340
2068 57387
2068 57575
2070 55888
2070 55836
2070 55845
2070 59880
2070 55980
2070 55844
2070 57385
2070 55890
2070 56580
2070 56120
2072 54418
2072 55888
2072 55389
2072 55944
2072 55426
2073 53892
2073 53898
2074 53074
2074 67864
2076 51896
2076 51798
2076 51900
2076 57782
2077 51188
2079 50004
2079 53892
2079 51282
2080 49425
2080 49440
2080 49900
2080 79840
2080 49426
2080 49504
2080 51896
2080 49920
2080 64870
2080 49465
2080 52000
2084 47269
2086 46263
2090 44380
2090 44910
2090 44385
2090 44460
2096 41916
2096 41920
2097 41940
2098 41055
2100 40304
2100 40419
2100 40305
2100 74850
2100 49900
2100 40650
2100 40400
2100 40306
2100 41916
2100 40320
2100 52395
2100 40425
2100 41650
2100 62874
2100 40530
2100 42000
2100 40775
2103 39256
2104 38922
2104 38924
2106 38232
2106 40419
2106 38220
2106 38922
2106 38961
2107 37924
2107 37926
2108 37570
2108 37572
2109 37924
2109 37259
2109 37962
2109 55389
2112 36341
2112 36344
2112 36608
2112 38423
2112 36366
2115 35928
2115 35532
2115 35485
2117 34930
2118 34652
2120 34930
2120 59880
2120 34132
2121 33932
2121 33936
2125 32880
2125 33932
2125 34000
2128 32178
2128 32368
2128 55888
2128 32186
2128 32528
2128 33250
2130 31728
2130 31737
2132 31291
2132 31330
2132 31488
2133 31077
2134 30866
2135 30658
2135 30660
2135 30744
2136 30456
2136 30616
2139 29940
2139 29946
2140 29940
2140 29960
2141 29472
2142 29284
2142 29286
2142 29316
2142 29988
2144 28942
2144 28944
2145 29940
2145 28743
2145 38922
2146 28942
2146 28564
2146 28971
2147 28443
2147 37924
2148 28443
2148 29893
2151 27724
2152 27944
2152 27976
2153 27372
2154 27284
2156 26946
2156 26901
2156 27445
2156 26950
2156 32934
2156 27489
2159 26452
2160 26289
2160 26946
2160 26352
2160 26320
2160 27000
2160 26290
2160 29940
2160 26640
2163 25853
2163 25956
2166 25449
2167 25300
2169 25025
2170 24950
2170 24893
2170 24955
2170 25172
2171 26052
2175 24950
2175 28942
2178 23952
2178 23892
2178 23958
2180 23653
2181 23532
2184 23952
2184 27944
2184 41916
2184 23192
2184 23205
2184 23296
2185 23085
2193 33932
2196 21956
2196 22455
2196 21960
2200 21550
2200 21956
2200 21560
2200 27445
2200 22000
2202 21336
2204 21150
2205 21060
2205 21420
2205 21070
2208 20832
2208 20958
2208 20792
2212 20459
2212 20958
2212 20461
2212 21014
2214 26946
2214 20459
2218 19960
2218 19962
2220 19782
2220 19960
2220 19785
2220 22455
2220 19795
2220 19980
2224 19472
2226 19320
2227 19244
2232 18879
2232 18910
2233 18821
2238 18463
2240 18324
2240 19960
2240 18340
2241 18260
2241 18426
2242 18644
2244 18062
2244 21956
2244 18084
2244 18326
2246 17964
2246 17968
2247 17964
2247 17869
2247 17976
2250 17964
2250 18000
2254 17465
2254 17444
2255 17380
2256 17328
2256 17625
2259 17964
2260 17087
2260 17090
2260 17465
2262 17004
2268 16686
2268 16646
2268 20958
2274 16327
2275 16276
2277 16174
2277 16236
2286 15734
2286 17964
2286 15748
2288 15640
2288 16467
2289 15596
2290 15572
2292 15469
2292 15456
2292 15471
2294 15469
2301 15104
2304 14970
2304 14976
2305 14970
2310 14684
2310 14970
2310 14700
2310 14685
2316 14471
2316 14475
2320 14384
2320 14471
2320 14500
2321 14256
2322 14319
2329 13972
2329 13974
2330 13972
2330 13980
2331 13972
2331 13986
2337 13680
2338 13972
2338 14028
2340 13590
2340 13585
2340 19461
2345 13972
2346 13379
2346 13524
2349 13284
2349 14471
2352 13200
2352 13188
2352 13328
2353 13156
2359 12974
2363 12852
2380 12475
2380 17465
2380 12376
2380 12495
2385 12240
2394 13972
2394 12012
2396 11976
2396 11980
2397 11976
2400 11976
2400 12000
2400 12475
2408 11976
2412 11573
2412 11574
2413 11550
2418 11440
2424 11976
2424 11312
2430 11178
2432 11136
2432 11134
2434 11092
2440 10978
2440 10980
2442 10978
2442 10989
2448 10812
2450 10780
2453 10978
2460 10590
2465 10540
2466 10479
2478 10262
2478 10266
2480 10230
2484 10160
2484 10212
2495 9981
2495 9982
2495 9984
2495 9988
2495 9996
2495 10479
2495 10978
2495 11976
2495 13972
2495 17964
2495 9985
2495 9990
2495 10000
2495 10020
2495 10060
2495 12475
2495 14970
2495 19960
2495 10005
2495 10030
2495 10080
2495 10180
2495 10380
2496 9980
2496 9984
2497 9988
2499 9996
2500 9980
2500 10000
2505 10020
2511 9732
2515 10060
2520 9600
2520 9980
2520 9630
2530 9460
2532 9429
2534 9412
2541 9317
2548 9282
2558 9085
2560 9060
2568 8982
2568 8988
2574 8982
2574 8892
2576 8865
2580 8818
2580 8820
2580 14970
2584 8772
2595 8650
2604 10479
2604 8556
2620 8384
2624 8340
2625 8330
2625 8400
2626 8320
2628 8982
2630 8280
2640 8184
2640 8250
2646 8127
2662 7984
2662 7986
2664 7984
2664 7992
2672 7984
2672 8016
2695 7700
2703 7632
2704 7984
2710 7588
2717 7524
2722 7485
2724 7485
2724 7491
2727 7474
2728 7440
2730 7485
2736 7380
2737 7378
2740 7485
2745 7320
2754 7252
2769 7150
2788 7038
2788 8483
2789 7020
2796 6986
2796 6990
2800 6986
2800 7000
2808 6912
2808 6903
2814 6986
2816 6864
2820 6831
2830 6773
2839 6722
2852 6670
2856 6630
2856 6664
2872 6544
2884 6487
2884 6489
2886 6487
2890 6460
2898 6417
2904 6384
2924 6321
2937 6230
2964 6162
2968 6095
2970 6105
2972 6078
2980 6045
2994 5989
2994 5990
2994 5992
2994 5996
2994 6004
2994 6487
2994 6986
2994 7984
2994 9980
2994 5991
2994 5994
2994 6000
2994 6012
2994 6036
2994 7485
2994 8982
2994 11976
2994 5997
2994 6006
2994 6024
2994 6060
2994 6132
2994 10479
2995 5988
2995 5990
2996 5988
2996 5992
2997 5988
2997 5994
2998 5988
2998 5996
3000 5988
3000 6000
3002 6004
3003 5988
3006 5988
3006 6012
3012 5988
3016 5902
3018 6036
3020 5889
3021 5883
3024 5872
3030 5988
3069 5709
3081 5668
3105 5589
3117 5550
3149 5452
3180 5361
3200 5305
3213 5292
3234 5236
3250 5200
3252 5168
3276 5109
3280 5125
3281 5100
3282 5094
3283 5092
3290 5076
3310 5028
3327 4990
3328 4990
3328 4992
3330 4990
3330 4995
3332 4990
3332 4998
3335 4990
3340 4990
3340 5010
3342 4956
3360 4990
3367 4914
3380 4875
3390 4854
3402 4830
3423 4788
3448 4741
3456 4736
3456 4725
3460 4990
3493 4658
3493 4660
3493 4990
3493 5988
3493 4662
3493 4676
3493 6986
3493 4690
3493 4788
3495 4660
3500 4645
3507 4676
3512 4624
3556 4550
3582 4508
3591 4494
3593 4491
3594 4491
3596 4491
3596 4495
3600 4491
3600 4480
3600 4500
3609 4491
3610 4465
3636 4491
3640 4420
3648 4408
3660 4392
3682 4359
3685 4355
3696 4340
3708 4326
3745 4280
3748 4270
3780 4230
3824 4176
3840 4160
3852 4491
3870 4122
3920 4080
3930 4056
3938 4048
3948 4037
3960 4026
3982 4004
3992 3993
3992 3994
3992 3996
3992 4000
3992 4008
3992 4024
3992 4056
3992 4491
3992 4990
3992 5988
3992 7984
3993 3993
3994 3994
3996 3996
4000 4000
4008 4008
4024 4024
4491 5988
4491 4491
4990 5988
4990 4990
5988 5988
```

Comment: Good practice(+1),but how to extend it to general case?

Comment: My script takes less than 2 seconds to run.