# About an old conjecture

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

In the page on the [Erdős-Straus conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Straus_conjecture), the result is conjectured to be true for all $n>1$:

$$(4/n)-((1/x)+(1/y)+(1/z))=0⇔nxy+nxz+nyz-4xyz=0$$

My **question** is about this generalized version:

$$(d/n)-((1/x)+(1/y)+(1/z))=0⇔nxy+nxz+nyz-dxyz=0$$

where $d$ is a positive integer.

(1) Can some one give me a counterexample for certain value of $d$.

(2) Why the presence of $4$ in the equation makes strong believes that the result is true.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/450280/erdős-straus-conjecture/2435778#2435778

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that we have $$\frac{d}{n}-[\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}]=\frac{d}{n}-[\frac{x+y}{xy}+\frac{1}{z}]=\frac{d}{n}-[\frac{xy+xz+yz}{xyz}]=0$$ $$\implies nxy+nyz+nxz -dxyz=0$$

Note that the Erdős–Straus Conjecture talks about expressing the fraction $\frac{4}{n}$ as a sum of three distinct fractions with numerator $1$ for $n\geq 2$.

For the second part, see the [Generalisations section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Straus_conjecture#Generalizations) in the same Wiki page.