# Find $\text{min} (a+b+c)$ if $a, b, c$ are distinct positive integers such that $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{c} = \frac{1}{42}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification

May I know if my solution is correct? Is there a more elegant way to tackle this problem? Thank you very much.

By Cauchy schwarz inequality, $(a+b+c)\left(\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{1}{b}+\dfrac{1}{c}\right) \ge9 \Rightarrow a+b+c\geq 378,$ with equality if $a=b=c=126.$

Let $c=126,$ then $\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{1}{b}=\dfrac{1}{63}.$ By Cauchy schwarz, 
$(a+b)\left(\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{1}{b}\right)\geq 4 \Rightarrow a+b\geq 252.$

Assume $ b < 252.$ Since $a=\dfrac{63^2}{b-63}+63$ it follows that $ b-63 < 189$ and $(b-63) \mid 63^2.$ Checking the factors of $63^2$ no bigger than $189$, $\text{min}(a+b) = 144+112=256.$ We can check if there exists distinct $a, b$ such that $a+b = 253, 254$ or $255,$ then $\text{min}(a+b)=256$ again.

Next, let us show that $\text{min}(a+b+c) = 144+112+126=382.$ It suffices to show there exists no integer solution to $a+b+c = 381, 380$ or $379.$

Let $a+b+c = S$. Assume wlog $43\leq a < 126.$ $\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{1}{b}+\dfrac{1}{c}=\dfrac{1}{42} \Leftrightarrow b^2-(S-a)b+\dfrac{42a(S-a)}{a-42}=0.$

We require the determinant $D=(S-a)^2+\dfrac{168a(S-a)}{a-42} \geq 0.$

For $S=381,$ $D\geq 0 \Leftrightarrow  \dfrac{255}{2} - \dfrac{\sqrt{1017}}{2}< 112\leq a \leq 142 < \dfrac{255}{2} + \dfrac{\sqrt{1017}}{2}.$ Since $a<126,$ it follows that $112 \leq a \leq 125.$

We can rewrite $D=(381-a)^2+168a-339\times 168-\dfrac{339\times 168\times 42}{a-42}.$

For $a\in \{112, ...,125\} \setminus \{114\}, (a-42) \in \{70, ...,83\} \nmid 339 \times 168\times 42,$ hence $b \not\in \mathbb{Z}.$

If $a = 114, \ D = 267 \Rightarrow \sqrt{D} \not\in \mathbb{Q} \Rightarrow b \not \in \mathbb{Z}.$

For $S = 380, $ following previous argument, we require $D = (380-a)^2+168a-338\times 168-\dfrac{338\times 168 \times 42}{a-42} \geq 0, $ so  $114\leq a \leq 125.$

For $a\in \{115, ...,125\} \setminus \{114\}, (a-42) \nmid 338 \times 168\times 42,$ hence $b \not\in \mathbb{Z}.$

If $a=114, \ b = c = 133.$ But $b,c$ are distinct.

We can argue similarly that there are no integer  solutions to $a+b+c = 379.$

Comment: Seems legal. Another $(x,y,z)$ with $x+y+z=382$ is [$(110, 132, 140)$](https://tio.run/##PYw9bsMwDIV3n4KdQgIKYiUdCgPq6DlXUGO5FWpRAsUAti/vxmnR6f19eGXRr8yXtyLbNkpOMIq/acxcIaaSRaH/K8BX6JsnEzWI5jz9M0XycL/pjlybIpEVmxQZEWezmD2uRDBmgUeGyHBF8fwZ0BrbtpaMhBK8ujNBHAFX27n@sb2e6bjr/CsL0XsLngc4nA7AWfenqoJr5@xptUTmOyxu8ulj8DB3OAXGGhSnWBVnInpxF1Pv6ekb2rYf)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/450280/erd%C5%91s-straus-conjecture/2435778#2435778